# Animating heatmap for google-maps-api-3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

This is driving me bananas...

I'm using google maps api v3, with the heatmap. I have successfully plotted data points, no problems there. But, I would like to have an animation that loops infinitely. Currently, I have the following code. (The map appears, but without any data points.)

```
var _data = [];
pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(_data);
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: pointArray,
});

heatmap.setData(_data);
heatmap.setMap( map );

play = function(){
    for( var j = 0; j < data_arr.length; j++ ){
        pointArray.clear();

        for( var i = 0; i < data_arr[j].length; i++ ){
            pointArray.push( new google.maps.LatLng(data_arr[j][i]['lat'], data_arr[j][i]['lon']) );
        }

        setInterval(function(){
            play();
        }, 3000);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function(){
    play();
});
```

Any help, is most welcome!

Comment: Can you post a link to what you've tried? If it isn't on a live web server use JSFiddle.

Comment: Absolutely: http://jsfiddle.net/T5RrR/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the heatmap data doesn't update until the currently executing script pauses. By that time, all of the data changes have been made so there is nothing to animate.

Unfortunately this means that a simplistic approach isn't going to work. Instead of changing the data in a direct loop, you are going to have to divide the data into animation steps, change only a few data points and then use setTimeout to call the next step in the chain. This will give a pause so that the library has a chance to actually make the changes you've specified.

In addition, your use of `setInterval` is incorrect (I believe you mean `setTimeout` in this case). You are calling `setInterval` in a loop and never clearing it. Each iteration of the loop causes a new timed execution so that it doesn't take long for you to have hundreds of intervals all calling your `play` function. `setTimeout` only will execute one more time.

Comment: It took a few more days of work, but got it running. Thanks Chad!

Comment: the fiddle doesnt seem to work, but looks like the timeout code has been added, is this working?